# Is there any need to move or change the repositories from the licenced version to the free version. or is there any task which is required for this?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I am using a user-based licence version of SVN, but now I can use the free version because of fewer users. SVN server is free for 10 users. Is there any need to move or change the repositories from the licenced version to the free version. or is there any task which is required for this? Please guide.

is there any task of SVN Admin required for moving from licensed user to free version?

Answer (score 0):

The free VisualSVN Server Community license allows for up to **15 user accounts**. I have to mention this because you said 10 accounts.

To switch from a paid license to the free one, click **Switch to Community License** on the Licensing tab in VisualSVN Server Properties.
[image]

Note that you may need to disable some features that are unavailable with the free license (if they are currently enabled with your paid license).

For more information on licensing, refer to the corresponding section of the [documentation](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/documentation/#Licensing) page and to the [Licensing](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/licensing/) page.